# Where can I access raw info from firefox about:support

Tags: python, firefox

Does anyone know where can I access to about:support data since i just want raw data from that page without opening firefox?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get info from this page is over python libraries os and sys.

I needed that data to create current user-agent based on OS but without opening firefox and sending request. I have added firefox to path but I could not call it like that in python I had to specify full path to the Firefox.

This py below updates itself to the latest version of firefox I hope it will help to someone:

```
import subprocess,re
from datetime import datetime
FIREFOX = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:{0}.{1}) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/{0}.{1}"
VERSION = re.compile('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)')
DATE = re.compile('DATE_CHECKED\s+=\s+"(.*?)"',re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
CDEF = re.compile('DEFAULT\s*=\s*"\d+\.\d+"',re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
DAYS_BEFORE_CHECK = 30
DATE_CHECKED = "2018-04-13"  # Don't change manually
DEFAULT = "59.0"  # Don't change manually


def get_user_agent():
    with open("UserAgent.py") as f:
        program_data = f.read()
        date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
        last_date = datetime.strptime(DATE.search(program_data).group(1), date_format)
        today = datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime(date_format), date_format)
        days = abs(today - last_date).days
        if days >= DAYS_BEFORE_CHECK:
            rebuild1 = re.sub(DATE.search(program_data).group(1), str(datetime.now().strftime(date_format)),
                              program_data)

            x = subprocess.check_output([FIREFOX, '-v', "|", "more"])
            version_no = x.strip()
            try:
                a, b, c = VERSION.search(version_no.decode()).groups()
            except:
                raise FileNotFoundError("Check firefox path")

            rebuild2 = CDEF.sub('DEFAULT = "{0}.{1}"'.format(a, b), rebuild1)
            with open("UserAgent.py", "w") as f:
                f.write(rebuild2)

    return USER_AGENT.format(*DEFAULT.split("."))
```